# How to prevent a temporary on the left hand side of the assignment operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

If I define `operator+` for a type, in the usual fashion

```
struct S {};

S operator+(S const &, S const &) { 
  return {}; 
}
```

users of `S` can write code like

```
S s{};
s + s = S{}; // huh
```

From what I can tell, `operator+` returns a temporary object of type `S`, which is then assigned to. The object then dies at the end of the statement, because there's no name for it, and so the statement is effectively a no-op.

I don't see any use for code like that, so I would like to make that a compile error. Is there a way to do that? Even a warning would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found what I need [here](https://isocpp.org/blog/2013/06/quick-q-should-i-return-a-const-value-stackoverflow). Apparently I can make the assignment operator only bind to lvalues.

```
struct S {
    S& operator=(S const&) & // only binds to lvalues
    { 
      return *this; 
    }
};
```

Now I get exactly the error I want.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to prevent this from happening is to return a constant object:

```
const S operator+(S const &, S const &) { 
    return {}; 
}
```

That will now result in a compilation error, in this situation, but

```
s= s + s;
```

will still work just fine.

This, of course, has a few other ramifications, and may or may not have undesirable side-effects, which may or may not pose an issue, but that would be a new question, here...