# Is there a use-case for std::string's operator= to not be lvalue ref-qualified?

Tags: c++, stdstring, rvalue, temporary, ref-qualifier

The post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61141894/why-is-stdstrings-member-operator-not-lvalue-ref-qualified) points out that `std::string`'s member `operator=` is not lvalue ref-qualified. That allows us to write code such as this:

```
std::string() = "Hello";
```

The linked post asks why this is allowed. The answer is backwards compatibility:

> Changing the definition of something in the standard library is not
> something to be undertaken lightly, as it could needlessly break
> existing code.

This is not unreasonable. Perhaps someone has written code such as

```
// Does useful stuff
// Does useful stuff


std::string{} = "Hello"; // Does nothing


// Does useful stuff
// Does useful stuff
```

by accident. Making `std::string::operator=` lvalue ref-qualified would prevent this old code from compiling, even if the program performs exactly as the programmer wants it to.

In the linked post, the user asks for a use-case, but one is not given. That is the question of this post.

#### The question

Is there a line of code that both

1. would not compile with `std::string::operator=` lvalue ref-qualified

and

2. if deleted would change the behavior of the program it is located in?

#### Note

Of course, by line of code, I do not mean code such as

```
std::string{} = "Hello"; ++i;
```

Comment: If `std::string() = x;` is deleted, where `x` is of a type that has a conversion operator to `std::string`, that conversion operator will not be called, and any side effects of the call will not happen. But maybe you think this scenario is not realistic, or that if this realistically happened, it wouldn't "break" the program.

Answer (score 1):

Before [`shrink_to_fit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/shrink_to_fit) was available, a common idiom to make sure a string's memory was free'd was to swap your string with a temporary one:

```
std::string().swap(some_string);
```

I guess someone could have written this post C++11 using the assignment to temporary as well:

```
std::string() = std::move(some_string);
```

So this would no longer compile if the overload was only l-value qualified.

Also, IIRC `shrink_to_fit` is non-binding, so you essentially still have to do this to guarantee deallocation.

Comment: I doubt this is a valid example. The template function `std::move` and `basic_string& operator=( basic_string&& str );` were introduced at the same moment, thus nobody would use `std::string() = std::move(some_string);` if there was only `basic_string& operator=( basic_string&& str)&` declared.

Comment: @273K Right, but my reading of the question is it asks about the current state or the world, not a hypothetical one where the overload was deleted when C++11 was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all know [why templates can only be implemented in the header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). This is a rule, but there are exceptions, as always.

Suppose someone wants to develop a template class library and whishes to hide library's code and restrict its templates for using only with types `int` and `float`. They design the header file:

```
// library.h
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct Int {
  operator std::string() const;  // implicit stringifier
  const T& get() const;
 private:
  T n;
};
```

They implement the template class member in the library.

```
// library.cc
#include "library.h"

template <typename T>
Int<T>::operator std::string() const & { a = n; return ""; }
```

Some other uses the library.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "iostream"
int main() {
  Int<int> i;
  std::cout << static_caststd::string(i);
}
```

They get linker errors:

```
main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Int<int>::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >[abi:cxx11]() const'
```

The class member functions were not called in the library, thus were not instantiated. The solution is calling them (with forcing side effects if needed.)

```
// library.cc
#include "library.h"

namespace {
int a;
}

template <typename T>
__attribute__ ((noinline)) Int<T>::operator std::string() const { a = n; return ""; }

int init() {
  std::string() = Int<float>();
  std::string() = Int<int>();
  return 0;
}

int inited = init();
```

See the example https://godbolt.org/z/Y95PbTYf9.

`std::string() = Int<float>();` was short and legal in C++98, for sure it was used and the committee wanted to keep the compatibility by not accepting the restrictions.